# Menu isn't showing all of the items

Tags: html, css

My drop down menu isn't showing all the items.  It stops after applications when there is more to it
Heres my code.

```css
/* TYPOGRAPHY */
body {
    color: #2e2e2e;
    font: 16px/24px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;   
}

h1,
h3, {
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  font-weight: 400; 
  z-index: 2;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 55px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
}
h4 {
  color: #5c5d60;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
a {
  color: #f46151;
  text-decoration: none;
}

    a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }        
    
    
    /* General LAYOUT RULES */
    .container {
      width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }                      
     .row {
       overflow: hidden;
     }
    .column-half {  
      margin: 0 12px 24px 12px;
      width: 576px;
      float: left;
    }         
    .container-center {
      margin: 0 auto 
    }
    
    /* HEADER */
    .header-homepage {
      background: url(../images/header-homepage.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
      height: 600px;
      background-size: 100%;
      
      margin-bottom: 96px;
    }      
      .header-about {
      background: url(../images/header-about.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
      height: 330px;
      background-size: 100%;
      
      margin-bottom: 96px;
    }                               
    
    .logo {
      float:left;
    }                        

/* NAV */
.clearfix:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
/* Menu */
.menu-wrap {
  width:100%;
  box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,255);
}
.menu {
  width:1000px;
  margin 0px:auto;
}
.menu li{
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
  font-family:'san-seriff';
}
.menu a {
  transition:all linear 0.15s;
}
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:grey;
}
/* top level */
.menu > ul > li {
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font-size:19px;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px  1 px 0px;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover >a, .menu > ul > .current-tem > a {
  background:white;
}

/* bottom */
.sub-menu {
  width:160%;
  padding:5px 0px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
  box-shadow:0px 2px 3px;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index:1;
  opacity:1;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display:block;
  font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
padding:10px 30px;
display:block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: white;
}
        
    .top-container {
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 48px 0;
    }            
    
.header-hr {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,255, .1);
  border: 0; 
  height: 1px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 96px;
}

.header-contents {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 200px;
}

  .header-contents p {
    margin-bottom: 48px;
  }
  
  /* BUTTONS */
  
  .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 48px;
    width: 200px;
    
    border: 1px solid #f2ae5d;
    color: #f2ae5d;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
    .btn:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #f2ae5d;
      color: #2e2e2e;
    }  
    
    /* FOOTER */
    footer {
      background-color: grey;
      padding: 24px 0;
      margin-top: 48px;
    }
      footer p {
        color: white;
      }
    .copyright {
      padding: 48px 0;
      text-align: center;
    }                   
    
    /* Sidebar */
    .sidebar {
      width: 400px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 48px;
    }                     
        .sidebar ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          padding: 0;
        }            
        
        .sidebar ul .active a {
          color: #2e2e2e;
        }
    
    .main-content {
      width: 752px;
      float: right;    
      margin-bottom: 48px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Alternative Reality</title> 
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="header-homepage">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="top-container">
              <!-- Logo -->
              <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
           
           <!-- MENU -->    
           <div class="menu-wrap">
           <nav class="menu">
              <ul class="clearfix">
                  <li><a href="#">Menu<img scr="images/arrow-down.svg"></a>  
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Applications</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Arw3Rw2LtNijv81PhBQUur4k6h6uTRAzYwyTLn30ios/viewform?usp=send_form">Trial Moderator</a></li>
                          <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/17ZRJm1sLBril0RbnZxwMmX-HdieOnmNJw2TmsIP04-k/viewform?usp=send_form">Forum Moderator</a></li>
                          <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/14fPUp6o-eTt5kKIpkjJcF8IXKbz7hd18zAvUZvLlu7E/viewform?usp=send_form">Advertising Staff</a></li>
                           <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://alternativereality.freeforums.net">Forum</a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/ardp">Join Group</a></li> 
                   <li><a href="#">Staff List</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
             
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  
              </ul>
           </nav> 
 </div>
       </div> <!-- end of top-container -->
     
     <hr class="header-hr">
     
     <div class="header-contents">
        <h1> Your dreams fully realized.</h1>
        
        <p>This is the time for everyone to band together and think about what you always wanted to do.  What your wishes would be on a server where you could literally do anything.  
        We take all the unneccesary clutter and people who are looking to stop you from..</p>
        
        <p><a href="about.html" class="btn">See Details</a></p>
        
     </div> <!-- end of header-contents -->   
  </div>  <!-- End container -->   
</header>

<!-- Content area -->
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="column-half">
            <a href="about.html"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" alt="Alt Reality"></a>
            
            <h3>Events</h3>
            
            <p> Take a look here for some of our upcoming events!</p>
            
            <p><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/ardp#events">See details &rarr;</a></p>
            </div> <!-- end of column-half -->
            <div class="column-half2">
            <a href="donate"><img src="images/picture2.jpg" alt="Alt Reality"></a>
            
            <h3>Features</h3>
            
            <p> We offer many features that are available to our members!</p>
            
            <p><a href="donate">See details &rarr;</a></p>
            </div> <!-- end of column-half -->
          </div> <!-- end -->
</div>  <!-- Content area -->


<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column-half">
           <!--VlexoFree_LinkBack-->    
        </div> <!-- end row-->
    </div> <!-- end container-->   
</footer>

<div class="copyright">
    <p>&copy; 2015 Mike G.</p>
    
</div> <!-- end copyright-->
</body>

</html>
```

It also appears that the menu isn't even working here either.  Heres a GIF of what i am seeing when i open up the index.html 
http://gyazo.com/6369ada1b1406215359ddcb76430d7a2

Comment: I linked my entire index.html and style.css above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.top-container { overflow:hidden }
```

It's hidden because it cannot overflow the container. Removing the "overflow:hidden" from .top-container should resolve it, but maybe this will cause some others things to fix.